# GET request on website vs standalone

Tags: http, httpwebrequest

I'm a bit confused or maybe I don't fully understand http requests.

There is a website on which the search results are fetched through a GET request.  I can see the whole parameter list in Firebug and if I click "search" the results are displayed as you would expect. What I don't understand is if I take this request URL (with the same parameters) and copy it in a new browser tab it doesn't return results anymore.  Instead I see a 500 - Internal server error.

Can someone explain why is this happening or what can I do to see the results when accessing the URL?

Comment: Are you sure it's a GET request? no parameters in POST? can you provide with the URL?

Comment: @darma there's only one request shown in firebug and that's a GET request

Comment: If you don't give us the URL it's hard to help.

Comment: It's possible that this page is checking the referer, which would be undefined if you just navigate straight to the url, and that an undefined referer causes some unexpected behaviour. All speculation of course, but I guess you could validate that by building another page that links to the search results page, both via a hyperlink and form submission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As robert_b_clark suggested the solution is to send the referrer header when making the request.